# Unsupported value: "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"

Tags: kubernetes

When I try to

```
kubectl create -f cloudflare-argo-rolebinding.yml
```

this RoleBinding

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: cloudflare-argo-rolebinding
  namespace: default
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: cloudflare-argo
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: cloudflare-argo-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

I get this error :

```
The RoleBinding "cloudflare-argo-rolebinding" is invalid: subjects[0].apiGroup: Unsupported value: "rbac.authorization.k8s.io": supported values: ""
```

Any idea ? I'm on DigitalOcean using their new Kubernetes service if it helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think problem is using wrong `apiGroup`.

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: cloudflare-argo-rolebinding
  namespace: default
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: cloudflare-argo
  # apiGroup is ""(core/v1) for service_account
  apiGroup: ""
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: cloudflare-argo-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Comment: I think this answer is correct. Because this refers to default `ServiceAccount` and you should use `namespace: kube-system` if you have not changed it.

Comment: @Crou I update my answer. I did a mistake and you've shown this. So thank you. Actually the value for `namespace` field should be the one in which the `SeviceAccount` named `cloudflare-argo` exists. It's not just `kube-system`. If none is used,`default` namespace is used.

Answer (score 5):

ServiceAccount subjects are in the v1 API, which is apiGroup ""